# Tensorflow: correctly loading results from training - (image, label) from Tensorboard does not match loaded (image, label)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I have a trained neural network model that I'm trying to load with Tensorflow.

I trained the network on an (image, label) dataset, where the label is a 2D array. 
When I see the images and labels on Tensorboard, everything looks fine.

In seeing the results of the training with Tensorboard, I see that:

- The loss converges
- As expected, at the last step of training (in this case, step 98,275), the prediction looks very close to the ground-truth

When I load the results from training using the code below, however, the predicted label looks very different, while the *image* and ground-truth labels look fine. I am feeding the model images from the training set, which means that, because this model has seen the images before, the predicted label should look close to the ground-truth. It doesn't, and I'm wondering why the *loaded* *label* looks so different, when the label on Tensorboard looks great.

Possible reasons:

- There is something wrong with the way I am preprocessing the image (I find that processing the training images a certain way to the loaded model yields different predicted labels (the predictions still look bad, just different) (e.g. converting the image to float yields a different predicted label than if I had not converted it to float))
- I am not loading the model checkpoint correctly

I'm mostly asking this question to rule out the second point. **Is there anything wrong with the way I am restoring the model checkpoint below?**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

from datasets import dataset_factory
from deployment import model_deploy
from nets import nets_factory
from preprocessing import preprocessing_factory
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import scipy.misc
import sklearn

slim = tf.contrib.slim
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import check_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import nn
from tensorflow.python.ops import sets
from tensorflow.python.ops import sparse_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import state_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import variable_scope
from tensorflow.python.ops import weights_broadcast_ops
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'master', '', 'The address of the TensorFlow master to use.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'train_dir', '/tmp/tfmodel/',
    'Directory where checkpoints and event logs are written to.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_clones', 1,
                            'Number of model clones to deploy.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean('clone_on_cpu', False,
                            'Use CPUs to deploy clones.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('worker_replicas', 1, 'Number of worker replicas.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'num_ps_tasks', 0,
    'The number of parameter servers. If the value is 0, then the parameters '
    'are handled locally by the worker.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'num_readers', 4,
    'The number of parallel readers that read data from the dataset.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'num_preprocessing_threads', 4,
    'The number of threads used to create the batches.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'log_every_n_steps', 10,
    'The frequency with which logs are print.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'save_summaries_secs', 600,
    'The frequency with which summaries are saved, in seconds.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'save_interval_secs', 600,
    'The frequency with which the model is saved, in seconds.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'task', 0, 'Task id of the replica running the training.')

######################
# Optimization Flags #
######################

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'weight_decay', 0.00004, 'The weight decay on the model weights.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'optimizer', 'rmsprop',
    'The name of the optimizer, one of "adadelta", "adagrad", "adam",'
    '"ftrl", "momentum", "sgd" or "rmsprop".')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'adadelta_rho', 0.95,
    'The decay rate for adadelta.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'adagrad_initial_accumulator_value', 0.1,
    'Starting value for the AdaGrad accumulators.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'adam_beta1', 0.9,
    'The exponential decay rate for the 1st moment estimates.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'adam_beta2', 0.999,
    'The exponential decay rate for the 2nd moment estimates.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('opt_epsilon', 1.0, 'Epsilon term for the optimizer.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('ftrl_learning_rate_power', -0.5,
                          'The learning rate power.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'ftrl_initial_accumulator_value', 0.1,
    'Starting value for the FTRL accumulators.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'ftrl_l1', 0.0, 'The FTRL l1 regularization strength.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'ftrl_l2', 0.0, 'The FTRL l2 regularization strength.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'momentum', 0.9,
    'The momentum for the MomentumOptimizer and RMSPropOptimizer.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('rmsprop_decay', 0.9, 'Decay term for RMSProp.')

#######################
# Learning Rate Flags #
#######################

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'learning_rate_decay_type',
    'exponential',
    'Specifies how the learning rate is decayed. One of "fixed", "exponential",'
    ' or "polynomial"')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'Initial learning rate.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'end_learning_rate', 0.0001,
    'The minimal end learning rate used by a polynomial decay learning rate.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'label_smoothing', 0.0, 'The amount of label smoothing.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'learning_rate_decay_factor', 0.94, 'Learning rate decay factor.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'num_epochs_per_decay', 2.0,
    'Number of epochs after which learning rate decays.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_bool(
    'sync_replicas', False,
    'Whether or not to synchronize the replicas during training.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'replicas_to_aggregate', 1,
    'The Number of gradients to collect before updating params.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
    'moving_average_decay', None,
    'The decay to use for the moving average.'
    'If left as None, then moving averages are not used.')

#######################
# Dataset Flags #
#######################

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'dataset_name', 'duration', 'The name of the dataset to load.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'dataset_split_name', 'train', 'The name of the train/test split.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'dataset_dir', 'data/trainTFrecords', 'The directory where the dataset files are stored.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'labels_offset', 0,
    'An offset for the labels in the dataset. This flag is primarily used to '
    'evaluate the VGG and ResNet architectures which do not use a background '
    'class for the ImageNet dataset.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'model_name', 'vgg', 'The name of the architecture to train.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'preprocessing_name', 'vgg_16', 'The name of the preprocessing to use. If left '
    'as `None`, then the model_name flag is used.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'batch_size', 1, 'The number of samples in each batch.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'train_image_size', None, 'Train image size')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_number_of_steps', None,
                            'The maximum number of training steps.')

#####################
# Fine-Tuning Flags #
#####################

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'checkpoint_path', None,
    'The path to a checkpoint from which to fine-tune.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'checkpoint_exclude_scopes', None,
    'Comma-separated list of scopes of variables to exclude when restoring '
    'from a checkpoint.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'trainable_scopes', None,
    'Comma-separated list of scopes to filter the set of variables to train.'
    'By default, None would train all the variables.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean(
    'ignore_missing_vars', False,
    'When restoring a checkpoint would ignore missing variables.')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


dataset = dataset_factory.get_dataset(
        'duration', 'train', 'data/trainTFrecords')

network_fn = nets_factory.get_network_fn(
        FLAGS.model_name,
        num_classes=(dataset.num_classes - FLAGS.labels_offset),
        weight_decay=FLAGS.weight_decay,
        is_training=True)

preprocessing_name = FLAGS.preprocessing_name or FLAGS.model_name
image_preprocessing_fn = preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(
        preprocessing_name,
        is_training=True)

provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
          dataset,
          num_readers=FLAGS.num_readers,
          common_queue_capacity=20 * FLAGS.batch_size,
          common_queue_min=10 * FLAGS.batch_size)

[image, ground_truth_label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])
image = image_preprocessing_fn(image, 600, 800)
images, ground_truth_labels = tf.train.batch(
          [image, ground_truth_label],
          batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
          capacity=5 * FLAGS.batch_size, dynamic_pad=True)

batch_queue = slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
          [images, ground_truth_labels], capacity=2 * deploy_config.num_clones, dynamic_pad=True)

images, ground_truth_labels = batch_queue.dequeue()
images = tf.image.resize_images(images, (600, 800))
image_out = tf.squeeze(images)
logits, end_points = network_fn(images);

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with slim.queues.QueueRunners(sess):
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer());
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./data/logs/model.ckpt-98275.meta');
        saver.restore(sess, './data/logs/model.ckpt-98275');
        for i in range(3):
            im, ground_truth_label, predicted_label = sess.run([image_out, ground_truth_labels, logits])
            plt.imsave(str(i) + 'prediction' + '.png', predicted_label)
            plt.imsave(str(i) + 'image' + '.png', im)
            label = np.reshape(ground_truth_label, (50, 50))
            plt.imsave(str(i) + 'label' + '.png', ground_truth_label)
```